# what happends to iterator when i change vector

Tags: c++, iterator

can you clarify me iterators a bit?
what happens to iterator when i change vector?
If I have a vector and I make iterator to on of elements and then do few operations with vector. Like emplace few elements, delete few elements(not my iterated element). Where is iterator pointing now? To same element? To element on which is on same position, where iterated element once was? or where ?
thx

for example

```
std::vector<int> v = {10,20,30};
std::vector<int>::iterator low,low2;
low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20);         
low2= std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 30); 
v.emplace ( low, 20);
v.push_back(40);
```

where is low2 pointing now?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, one musnt use an old iterator after modification. What happens exactly depends on the implementation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterator is invalidated when the resulting new `size` is greater than the `capacity` before the call and using it will cause undefined behavior. A special case is the end iterator, which is invalidated in any case.

Answer (score 0):

After changing containers in C++, every stored iterator is potentially (most of the time) **invalidated**. So you should not use them unless you will have **undefined behavior**.

For [`.push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) and [`.emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace):

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and
>   references (including the past-the-end iterator) are **invalidated**.
>   Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is **invalidated**.